# Point Slope Form Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the equation $$2.2 - 3.6 = -0.1(x-14)$$

What am I doing wrong here?

$$-1.4 = -0.1x + 1.4$$
$$ 0 = 0.1x$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-1.4 = 0.1x + 1.4$$ looks good, but then you need to add $-1.4$ to both sides, which should yield

$$-2.8 = 0.1x$$
$$-28 = x$$

Comment: -.- I keep making these stupid errors. Thanks.

Comment: As long as we are counting sign errors.... we have $-1.4 = -0.1x +1.4$.  So $-2.8 = - 0.1x$ and $x = +28$.  So ... we all make these errors.....

Comment: This was a copying error and not an algebra error.  Good catch.